# Client and server sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, multiplayer

I've can't seem to figure out how to send and receive data between my existing sockets.  right now I am just trying to send one string back and forth and be able to see it.  Any help as to what i am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

the problem parts are here:

```
    char hostm[10];
    printw("you are host!\n");
    printw("Type the number you would like to pick %s: ", req.hostname);//gets row1
    scanw("%s", &hostm);
    printw("%s\n", hostm);

                write( (struct sockaddr *)&req.sa, &hostm, sizeof(hostm));
                char response[80];
                read( (struct sockaddr *)&resp.sa, &response, sizeof(response));

                printw("Response: %s\n", response);
    recvfrom(sock, (void *)&resp, sizeof (matchrequest), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &fromlen);
```

and

```
     char response[80];
char response2[80];
read( (struct sockaddr *) &host.sa, &response, sizeof(response));
read( (struct sockaddr *) &req.sa, &response2, sizeof(response2));
printf("\n\nresponse was %s\n%s\n", &response, &response2);
        write( (struct sockaddr *) &req.sa, &response, sizeof(response));
write((struct sockaddr *) &host.sa, &response2, sizeof(response2));
```

I don't know if its in the right place either, so here is all the code:

peer.c

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "match.h"

int sock;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
matchrequest req;
int matched = 0;

void *thread_start(void *args) {
int bytes_sent;
while(!matched) {
    printf("waiting for peers...\n");
    bytes_sent = sendto(sock, &req, sizeof(matchrequest), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof serveraddr);
    if (bytes_sent < 0) {
        printf("Error sending packet: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sleep(3);
}
}
void writeResponse(char * response) {
write(sock, &response, sizeof(response));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread_t th;
struct sockaddr_in sa; 

matchrequest resp;
ssize_t recsize;
socklen_t fromlen;


sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

if (argc != 3) {
    printf("specify name and game type for this peer!\n");
    return;
}

req.gametype = atoi(argv[2]);
req.state = 0;
strncpy(req.peername, argv[1], 100);

printf("using name: %s\n", req.peername);

memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sa.sin_port = 0;

if (-1 == bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)))
{
        perror("error bind failed");
        close(sock);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof serveraddr);
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(7652);
pthread_create(&th, NULL, &thread_start, NULL);

for (;;) 
{
    fromlen = sizeof(sa);
        recsize = recvfrom(sock, (void *)&resp, sizeof (matchrequest), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &fromlen);
        if (recsize < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    if (recsize != sizeof(matchrequest)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid datagram received");
        continue;
    }


    initscr();
        printw("matched with peer %s.  Game can start!\n", resp.peername);

    if(strcmp(resp.hostname, req.peername) == 0)
    {

        char hostm[10];
        printw("you are host!\n");
        printw("Type the number you would like to pick %s: ", req.hostname);//gets row1
        scanw("%s", &hostm);
        printw("%s\n", hostm);

                    write( (struct sockaddr *)&req.sa, &hostm, sizeof(hostm));
                    char response[80];
                    read( (struct sockaddr *)&resp.sa, &response, sizeof(response));

                    printw("Response: %s\n", response);
        recvfrom(sock, (void *)&resp, sizeof (matchrequest), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &fromlen);


    }
    else
    {
        char peerm[10];
                    printw("you are peer!\n");
                    printw("Type the number you would like to pick %s: ", req.peername);//gets row1
                    scanw("%s", &peerm);
                    printw("%s\n", &peerm);

                    // send to client, transmitted fine
                    write(sock, &peerm, sizeof(peerm));
                    char response[80];
                    read(sock, &response, sizeof(response));
                    // Prints the missing character symbol, and 'random' letters
                    printw("Response: %s\n", response);

    }
    endwin();
}
close(sock); /* close the socket */
return 0;
}
```

matchd.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "match.h"

#define MAX_REQUESTS 100

matchrequest ready[MAX_REQUESTS];
int outsock;

void handlerequest(struct sockaddr_in sa, matchrequest req) {

matchrequest host;
int idx = req.gametype % MAX_REQUESTS;

req.state = READY;
req.sa = sa;

printf("%s on %s:%d requested game type %d \n", req.peername, inet_ntoa(req.sa.sin_addr), req.sa.sin_port, req.gametype);

// if room, place in ready position
if (strncmp(ready[idx].peername, req.peername, 100) == 0) {
    // peer is just checking in
} else if (ready[idx].state == MATCHED) {
    ready[idx] = req;
    printf("%s selected as host.  waiting for peers...\n", req.peername);
    strcpy(req.hostname, req.peername);
} else {
// match with existing peer
    printf("%s matched with existing host\n", req.peername);
    req.state = MATCHED;
    host = ready[idx];
    host.state = HOST;
    ready[idx] = req;
    strcpy(req.hostname, host.peername);
    req.peermove = req.hostmove;
    req.hostmove = req.peermove;

    char response[80];
    char response2[80];
    read( (struct sockaddr *) &host.sa, &response, sizeof(response));
    read( (struct sockaddr *) &req.sa, &response2, sizeof(response2));
    printf("\n\nresponse was %s\n%s\n", &response, &response2);
            write( (struct sockaddr *) &req.sa, &response, sizeof(response));
    write((struct sockaddr *) &host.sa, &response2, sizeof(response2));

 //     read(outsock, &response, sizeof(response));
 //     printf("\n\nresponse was %s\n\n", &response);
 //     write(outsock, &response, sizeof(response));


    printf("sending response to %s at %s:%d\n", host.peername, inet_ntoa(host.sa.sin_addr), host.sa.sin_port);
    sendto(outsock, (void *) &req, sizeof(matchrequest), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &host.sa, sizeof(host.sa));
    printf("sending response to %s at %s:%d\n", req.peername, inet_ntoa(req.sa.sin_addr), req.sa.sin_port);
    sendto(outsock, (void *) &host, sizeof(matchrequest), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &req.sa, sizeof(req.sa));
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
}
}

int main(void)
{
int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
struct sockaddr_in sa; 
matchrequest req;
ssize_t recsize;
socklen_t fromlen;

outsock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sa.sin_port = htons(7652);

if (-1 == bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)))
{
        perror("error bind failed");
        close(sock);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} 
for (;;) 
{
    fromlen = sizeof(sa);
        printf ("receiving....\n");

        recsize = recvfrom(sock, (void *)&req, sizeof (matchrequest), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &fromlen);
        if (recsize < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    if (recsize != sizeof(matchrequest)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid datagram received");
        continue;
    }
    handlerequest(sa, req);
}
}
```

match.h

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>

 typedef enum matchstate {MATCHED = 0, READY, HOST} matchstate;

 typedef struct matchrequest {
    matchstate state;
    int gametype;
    char board[4][4];
    char covboard[4][4];
    int player1pts;
    int player2pts;
    int gameover;
    int turn;
    int hostmove;
    int peermove;
    char peername[100];
    char hostname[100];
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
 } matchrequest;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412264/how-to-send-info-across-berkeley-sockets  *sigh*

Comment: It will take good amount of time to analyze your code and find trouble.  Your best best is to make it very simple client server test app and then ask for problem if you still could not find. This one is good for bounty before someone spend time on it.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a simple tcp server that delivers the same message to multiple clients.

Comment: @JonBlake: What do you want us to do with all of that code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `read` and `write` expect file descriptors as the first argument, but you're providing something else entirely. See the documentation for [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/write.html) and note that you're not calling it the way you should be. Also, I didn't read all of your code but it appears as though it would generate a lot of warnings that you shouldn't ignore.

Also note, that `read` may return prematurely or it may block while it waits for more data to arrive. You have to cater for these situations yourself.

Also, keep in mind that with UDP, there is no guarantee or acknowledgement of delivery of data, unlike TCP. So although your program has sent the data, it may be lost in transmission to the clients.